# セレクトボックスにデータを渡したい(Laravel)

Tags: html, laravel

したい事

```
セレクトボックス(趣味)の中身
・散歩
・料理
・映画
```

があったとして、IDが1(趣味:散歩)の人なら、セレクトボックス(趣味)が散歩になっている状態にしたい。

今のコード(★★★★.blade.php)

```
<select name="type">
  @foreach($typeOption as $type => $displayName)
    <option value="{{ $type }}">{{ $displayName }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

という状態で、
セレクトボックスは作れるのですが、
各IDにあった項目が選ばれてない状態です。
(ID1の人のセレクトボックスが散歩になってない)

どなたかご回答のほど宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

ID 1 のユーザーが下記のようなデータを変数 $userdata に持っている想定で進めさせていただきます。

```
//ID 1 のユーザーデータ
$userdata = [
  'id' => 1,
  'hobby' => 1,
];
```

このような場合、以下のようにして特定の選択肢を選択状態にできます。

```
<select name="type">
  @foreach($typeOption as $type => $displayName)
    <option value="{{ $type }}" @if($userdata['hobby'] === $type) selected @endif>{{ $displayName }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

もし趣味データが users テーブルに規定してあり、 Auth::user() で当該情報を取得できる場合は、上記コードの $user['hobby'] を Auth::user()->hobby と書き換えると良いかと思います。